# Checking for certain words in a 2d array using chars(homework)

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a program that requires me to take in a input similar to the one below.
6   6
d e v o l g
r e d p h k
q c h z j c
p o a a f o
v a m m n l
q t f o x b
    The first two integers represent the rows and columns and then the rest represent the actual chars to be placed in the method. I have succesfully created a method that creates and reads in the array.
The program is a word search puzzle solver. It takes several methods but the one I need to focus on is the "checkUp" method and checkDown left right... So far, this is my code for this method.

```
public static boolean checkUp(char [][] puzzle, String word, int row, int col) {
        System.out.println("Row: " + row +  " Col: " + col + " Word: " + word.charAt(0) + " CurLet: " + puzzle[row][col] + " Word length: " + word.length());
        if (row==0) {
            return false;
        } else if (word.length()==1) {
            return true;
        } else if (word.charAt(0) == puzzle[row][col]){
            checkUp(puzzle,word.substring(1),row-1,col);            
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Some restrictions, I have to read the array and everything from it Char by char, I can’t convert it to a string. If they match I just shift the row count down by 1 to move up in this specific example.
Does anyone have any better ideas as to how to go about this? I'm completely stumped at this point and in fact lost. My friend helped me write up to this point, but I really lost track of what exactly he is trying to do.

Comment: Depends how you're expecting the 2D array to be setup given the input String. for example: is the input String formatted row by row? Column by Column?

Comment: Looks like checkUP, is actually checking left, the row you decrease by 1 every time, which is going left, to go up, you should do col - 1

Comment: Off topic but do you really need to check both up and down and also left and right? For normal crosswords you write vertically downwards and horizontally from left to right or the opposite depending on the language but not in both directions

Comment: For a solution I would turn each row or column checked into a string and use either `contains()` or `indexOf()`

Comment: Wouldn’t changing the column by -1 just have it check to the left instead? I’m not at my PC right now so I can’t test it. @joe

Comment: @joakim danielson, my teacher wants the method to go char by char and not a string as a whole. Additionally I have to write a method for each direction and for extra credit for the diaganols. (No idea how to spell that)

Comment: @sleeptoken the string input is just a word that has to be searched for in the 2d array.

Comment: Then make it clear it is homework and also the mentioned restrictions in the question itself.

Comment: @joakim danielson, my bad this is my first post.

Comment: This is a word search puzzle, not a crossword puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check if the word is not longer then the given row or col. Then you iterate over the word and compare chars...

```
public static boolean checkUp(char[][] puzzle, String word, int row, int col) {
    if (row + 1 - word.length() < 0) return false;

    for (int i = row; i > row - word.length(); i--) {
        if (puzzle[i][col] != word.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean checkRight(char[][] puzzle, String word, int row, int col) {
    if (col + word.length() > puzzle[row].length) return false;

    for (int i = col; i < col + word.length(); i++) {
        if (puzzle[row][i] != word.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```